# NAO with nao_path_follower?

Tags: ros, nao-robot, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

New to ROS world.

How to launch the package nao_path_follower ([nao_path_follower](http://wiki.ros.org/nao_path_follower)) ?

I've check the package github:

[the package github](https://github.com/ahornung/nao_extras/tree/master/nao_path_follower/src) , no launch file and config file.

Do I have to write the my launch file and config file to make this node been shown in the rosnode list?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225039/nao-with-nao_path_follower-?/) by [SHI.ZP](https://answers.ros.org/users/25720/shi.zp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2016-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is launched with `rosrun nao_path_follower nao_path_follower`.

---

Originally posted by [yasagitov](https://answers.ros.org/users/23174/yasagitov/) with karma: 223 on 2016-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0